# What is the way to implement 8b/10b encoder/decoder in FTDI chip?

Tags: ftdi, encoding

What I want to do is interface a Visible Light Communication link I have made to a computer using USB. I am regenerating the clock from the data at receiver end so I need clock recovery transition edges in the data, hence I want to use 8b/10b encoding. I am looking for bit-rate of 1Mbps.

I have heard about FTDI chips which interface the USB protocol on the hardware and give programmable access to GPIO pins. I have also previously directly used FT232 for USB to UART conversion.

1. Is it even possible to add an LUT to FTDI chip and program it to encode/decode?
2. If yes, how would I proceed and primarily what chip do I use?
3. Is it advisable to encode on the computer and send data? I am not 100% for this option because it would require breaking the encoded 10bit sequences to 8bit chunks for transfer on the computer.

Comment: I'd be curious to know what you think "LUT" stands for. Regardless, any reasonably fast microcontroller would be able to handle what you've described so far. It could decode the signal from the light sensor and dump the data to the FTDI chip. But you can also get microcontrollers that have USB built-in.

Comment: Unless you *really* need it, why pick 8b/10b? You mentioned some of the FTDI chips have UART, this is most certainly the easiest as A) It's got embedded clock already B) the encoders and decoders are *BUILT IN* to the chips right off the bat and C) I'd be amazed if it couldn't hit 1Mbps. Also, 8B/10B won't compensate for signal path loss, you'll need to work out your own automatic gain control system so that the received signals have the proper amplitudes for correct decoding (a limiting trans-impedance amplifier should do - Google will know... *Google knows all*)

Comment: @udiboy12079 Yes, look at low end FPGA and LUT suppliers, just send two 8 bit chunks to the computer. They already have an IRDA standard that already does this stuff.

Comment: Why go through all this trouble? Galvanic insulation?

Comment: At 1 Mbps you may as well use Manchester or biphase mark encoding rather than 8b/10b. If you can find the old HP Optoelectronics Application Guide from the mid-90's, (or google) you can generate this encoding with a couple of gates.

Comment: Wait a minute, Visible Light Communication.... won't he need some kind of modulation?

Comment: @Sam I have been using UART to test my modulation/demodulation hardware, and I know it will work for 1Mbps easily, but this is a course project and the professor expects a synchronous communication protocol. Anyway I dont need gain control, just DC balance. After transimpedance amplification, If I know the DC level well (currently I set it using a POT) a comparator does the job.

Comment: Dave, I meant a Lookup Table by "LUT". @laptop2d could you point me to the LUT suppliers you are talking about?

Comment: We don't really do that, against SE policy to recommend specific products. Here is something to get you started http://www.digikey.com/products/en?FV=fff40027,fff80165&k=cpld